# Why do I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c

I am new to C programming, and I'm trying to write a program in linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



 char num, fileName[260];
   int numCount, inp;
   FILE *fp, *nf;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){




   printf( "1. New file\n" );
   printf( "2. Display file\n" );
   printf( "3. Edit file\n" );
   printf( "4. Exit\n" );
   scanf( "%d", &inp );



   switch (inp){
    case 1:            
        displayFile();
       break;
    case 2:            
        printf("\n");
        break;
    case 3:            
        printf("\n");
        break;
    case 4:            
        printf("\n");
        break;
    default:            
        printf("\n");
        break;
   }




   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}



int displayFile(void){

    printf("Enter the name of file. \n");
    scanf("%s",fileName);
    fp = fopen(fileName,"r");


    if(!fp){

        printf("Error! Cannot open file \n");
        exit(1);
   }

    else{
        printf("The content of %s are :\n", fileName);

        while( ( num = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ) //End-of-file
            numCount++;
            printf("%c",num);

    }
        printf("There are %i numbers in file:\n", numCount);

}
```

This is what happens when I run the program:
It starts, gives me the case selection, I select "Display file", it gives me the "enter name of file". However I do not get choice to write before the "core dumped" error message appears.

Comment: "Display file" is No. 2 but it shouldn't give "enter name of file". What do you actually select?

Comment: I don't understand - what do I actually select? I wan't to be able to write the name of a file the program should display

Comment: Because your program has a bug? Any reason for using global variables?

Comment: Where else should I put them? It's just easier to have control over them like this at the moment

Comment: In the smallest relevant code block. `fd`, for example, is *only* used inside `displayFile`. (For plain C the "smallest relevant code block" would be a function.)

Comment: Blocks used in control strucure `if`, `while`, `for` can also be "smallest relevant code block", and you can write blocks inside functions without control structures.

Comment: @MikeCAT: that depends on the C version. As it is, OP's C is version agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is very wrong in the approach, you don't need to declare a single global variable in your program.

Among the problems there are:

1. You don't give a declaration (*prototype*) for `displayFile()` that could cause *undefined behavior*, and if you had compiler warnings enabled the compiler would warn about *implicit function declaration*.
2. Using global variables makes your code messy and potentially buggy.
3. You open the file in one function, and close it in another funcion and also you don't check for `NULL` before calling `fclose()` and since passing `NULL` to `fclose()` is undefined behavior it seems to be the actual problem.

   Openning the file in one funcion and closing it in antoher, is conceptually wrong. It's made possible in your program because of point 2.

   Global variables are dangerous because it's hard to track their state, you can modify it in a function, and miss that when using it in another. Moreover, global variables are very rarely needed.
4. You never check for `scanf()`'s return value, in the first `scanf()` it's very dangerous because it would cause undefined behavior when reading the `inp`.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int displayFile(void);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int inp;

    printf( "1. New file\n" );
    printf( "2. Display file\n" );
    printf( "3. Edit file\n" );
    printf( "4. Exit\n" );

    if (scanf("%d", &inp) != 1)
        return -1;
    switch (inp)
    {
    case 1:
        displayFile();
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("\n");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("\n");
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int displayFile(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char fileName[100];
    int numCount;
    int num;

    printf("Enter the name of file. \n");
    scanf("%99s", fileName);

    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        printf("The content of %s are :\n", fileName);
        while (( num = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
            numCount++;
        printf("%c", num);
        printf("There are %i numbers in file:\n", numCount);
        fclose(fp);

        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: As I said I am new to C, and I am now aware that my code is a mess. However I don't understand how NULL passes to fclose().

Also the code you added; closes after option 2 is chosen.

Comment: Being new to a language doesn't make it correct to write ugly code. It should be one of your priorities. Did you solve your problem? And regarding the options, it's your own code.

Comment: Not yet. I do not get the core dumped error, but it closes as soon as I choose option 2

Comment: Oh wait! I got it, it's working now. Thank you for your help

Comment: If you consider that this was helpful, please accept the answer. The thank you comments are not needed and actually discouraged on SO. Did you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Answer (score 2):

When you select `2. Display file`, `fp` is not assigned and its value is `NULL` since it is global variable which is not explicitly initialized.

`fclose` seems to crush when `NULL` is passed.

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fp;


int main(void){
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

emitted Segmentation Fault on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oqVNhw4aTlxNgiaa).

I think you should close the file not in `main` function but in `displayFile` function.

Also, you shouldn't have too many global variables: you should make some of them local.

Comment: Putting the fclose() in displayfile causes the program to quit as soon as I select displayFile

Comment: Be careful! You are contradicting yourself in this sentence: "its value is NULL since it is global variable which is not explicitly initialized". Uninitialized values are *not* NULL (and I even think `fclose`ing a NULL file pointer is explicitly allowed - it crashes because `fd` is *not* NULL).

Comment: The program crashed when `NULL` is passed to `fclose` in [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BBgYXfQN6NCN8q7R).

Comment: @Jongware `fclose(NULL);` is UB.

Comment: @CoolGuy: then I was confusing it with `free`. Still, Mike's statement is misleading. `fclose(uninitialized_variable);` is *also* bad.

Comment: @Jongware "_Uninitialized values are not NULL_" -- Correct me if I'm wrong, but `fp` *is* auto-initialized to `NULL` as it is a **global** pointer which is not explicitly initialized as Mike suggests. And yes, you were confusing `fclose(NULL);` with `free(NULL);`, which, OTOH, is legal and a no-op.